# HTML, Python, beginner. Trying to reference a variable from the post function

Tags: python, html

If the post function finds an error, I want it to communicate with the Get function so I can add the error to the main page.
How can this be done without templates?

Here is the code and also here is the solution video to the problem:
https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs253/lessons/48756009/concepts/485326480923#

```
import re
import cgi
import webapp2
# html boilerplate for the top of every page
page_header = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User-Signup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Signup</h1>
"""

# html boilerplate for the bottom of every page
page_footer = """
</body>
</html>
"""

USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
def valid_username(username):
    return username and USER_RE.match(username)
PASS_RE = re.compile(r'^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$')
def valid_password(password):
    return password and PASS_RE.match(password)
EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r'^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$')
def valid_email(email):
    return not email or EMAIL_RE.match(email)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        add_username = """
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <label>
                Username <input type="text" name="user_name" value = ""/>
            </label>
        </form>
        """
        add_password = """
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <label>
                Password <input type="password" name ="password" value = ""/>
            </label>
        </form>
        """
        validate_password = """
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <label>
                Password <input type="password" name ="password" value = ""/>
            </label>
        </form>
        """
#        error = self.request.get("error")
#        if error:
#            error_esc = cgi.escape(error, quote=True)
#            error_element = '<p class="error">' + error_esc + '</p>'
#        else:
        error_element = ''
        password_error = ''


        content = page_header + add_username + error_element + add_password + password_error + page_footer
        self.response.write(content)
    def post(self):
        error_element = ''
        have_error = False
        user_name = self.request.get("user_name")
        password = self.request.get("password")
        params = dict("")
        if not valid_username(user_name):
            error_element = "thats not a valid username"
            have_error = True
        if not valid_password(password):
            password_error = "thats not a valid password"
            have_error = True

        add_username = """
        <form method="post">
            <label>
                Username <input type="text" name="user_name" value = "{0}"/>
            </label>
        </form>
        """.format(user_name)
        add_password = """
        <form method="post">
            <label>
                Password <input type="password" name ="password" value = "{0}"/>
            </label>
        </form>
        """.format(password)
        validate_password = """
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <label>
                Password <input type="password" name ="password" value = "{0}"/>
            </label>
        </form>
        """.format(password_error)
        content = page_header + add_username + error_element + add_password + password_error + page_footer
        self.response.write(content)
```

Basically I need to be able to reference a variable from the Post function in the Get function. I am not allowed to use templates.

What I have tried:
I tried using a redirect with an error.. However this doesnt seem to be the way its done in the video.

Please help me.

Comment: which variable you want to use in which function? The question is unclear so far.

Comment: If the post function finds an error i want to return to the get and have the error be displayed

Comment: maybe im thinking about the problem in the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video you linked is behind a login page, but it sounds like you want to redirect to the url for MainHandler.get(), and encode the error or error code as a request parameter on the url. That would look like this:

```
# in your post():
def post(self):
    # your code here...
    if have_error:
        self.redirect(url + '?error=Your_Error_Here')
    else:
        self.response.write(content)

# in your get():
def get(self):
    error = self.request.get('error', None)
    if error is not None:
        # handle your error here
    else:
        # no error to handle
```

You normally have two options when you want an http POST handler to forward information to an http GET handler:

1. As shown above, redirect to the appropriate url with the information encoded on the url (that is the `?error=Your_Error_Here` part). I have often seen that used for error alerts and also confirmation messages if a form is posted successfully (think green checkmark on the screen after you hit "save")
2. Instead of sending the response from the post handler, you could actually call the get() handler from the post handler and respond with whatever response object comes out of that. In general, I would not recommend that.